# Using conditional formatting to highlight entire area instead of just one cell

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Here's a screenshot of the situation:

[image: situation]

When I hover over the rule to the right which I defined, the wanted area is highlighted entirely, so I would presume I entered everything correctly, but only one cell actually assumes the wanted color (the one in the top left corner).

What do I have to do so that the entire area becomes green if B1="September" (which it is)

[image: One more pic for clarification.]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to lock it down with **`$`** symbol otherwise:

- cell **F1** thinks that should look in **C1** for **`September`** ...
- and cell **E2** thinks that it should look in **B2** for **`September`** ...
- etc.

correct it to this: **`=$B$1="September"`**

[image]

Comment: That's smart, thank you very much.